# Trying to understanding VirtualBox linked clones

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, clone

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation in a virtual machine. I want to keep it that way except for Windows updates.

I now want to have a running Windows 10 with additional software. My thought is to create a linked clone of the original machine. Ideally it would inherit any further updates from the original.

There is a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31405537/117259) on cloning the machine, and the accepted answer implies that the linked clone essentially extends the original machine.

Is this correct? Can I create a linked clone to the original as a working copy?

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally it would inherit any further updates from the original.

I don't think that's possible.

Linked clones work at block level, **not at file level** – VirtualBox does not have the capability to overlay two NTFS filesystems or two Windows registries; all that it does is share the *disk sectors* of the virtual disks.

It's a "copy-on-write" system, like disk snapshots. Initially the clone starts with all its data (disk sectors) "borrowed" from the original, so that it doesn't need to occupy any space of its own. From that point on, however, the VMs can only *diverge* – if VM1 writes something new to a disk sector, VM2 still keeps a copy of the previous data for itself, and vice versa. In other words, writes done by VM1 are invisible to VM2; anything else would mean letting both VMs write to the same disk without being aware of what the other VM is doing, which won't end up with a working NTFS filesystem.